# django form.is_valid() returns 0 always in case of file upload

Tags: python, django

I have following form (along with two other forms):

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()
```

The following is my html:

```
<div class="panel panel-danger">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form action="" method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <legend>Upload a file: </legend>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Input field">
                        </div>



                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

File handling is done:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    print "I am in request."
    print request.FILES['file']
    # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
    formName = NameForm(request.POST)
    formHandle = HandleForm(request.POST)
    fileForm = UploadFileForm(request.POST)
    successMessages = []
    failureMessages = []
    # check whether it's valid:
    # 
    if fileForm.is_valid():
        print "file is uploaded."
        print request.FILES['file']
    else:
        print "File form is not set."
```

Always else condition is executed, even if the value in `request.files` is set. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read the manual:  form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: Sometimes, we get so involved in coding that we forget about reading the manual. Thanks by the way.

Comment: Yep :) That's true :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `request.FILES` as follows:

```
fileForm = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: What the hell, how did I miss this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No problem, it is normal to forget things like that sometimes. You can accept it as answer for your question :)